# Is it true that there are 2 wETH and do they differ in safety?

Tags: ether, wrapped-tokens

When miners mine on Ethermine, they can choose to get wETH, but it seems like it is [wrapped on Polygon](https://polygonscan.com/token/0x7ceb23fd6bc0add59e62ac25578270cff1b9f619?a=0xC771D45b386AF3B22bDE71e3Cf9799c222123055)?

It has the contract: `0x7ceb23fd6bc0add59e62ac25578270cff1b9f619`

I think there is also a [wETH that is an ERC20 token](https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/weth/), so it is wrapped on the Ethereum blockchain.

It has the contract: `0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2`

Is that true?  It also looks like one is [a Polygon contract](https://polygonscan.com/address/0x7ceb23fd6bc0add59e62ac25578270cff1b9f619), while the other one is [an Ethereum contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2).

So supposedly the wETH on Polygon should be exchangeable for a wETH on Ethereum, and in turn exchangeable for an ETH? However, isn't it true that if Polygon is hacked (God forbids), then the wETH on Polygon can be affected, while if it is wETH on Ethereum, it may be more protected because there are perhaps more people who are concerned with the health of Ethereum?  That is, there is one wETH that is tied to the safety and security of Polygon, and another wETH that is tied to the safety and security of Ethereum?